# why I cannot get result on console when implement binary search in python, using Sublime?

Tags: python, algorithm, sublimetext2, binary-search

I'm new here. Today I tried to implement binary search algorithm in python, using editor Sublime. But why no result shown on my console, as it should be "1"? I checked my code, unable to find anything wrong. I'm really confused now. Many thanks if you could help!

```
def binary_search(list,item):
    low=0
    high=len(list)-1

    while low<=high:
        mid=(low+high)/2
        guess=list[mid]

        if guess==item:
            return mid
        elif guess>item:
            high=list[mid]-1
        else: 
            low=list[mid]+1

    return None 

my_list=[1,3,5,7,9]

print binary_search(my_list,3)
```

Comment: @aryamccarthy He only returns `None` when the search fails. It's iterative, not recursive.

Comment: I C !!!!! Thank you so much, Barmar!

Answer (score 1):

`high` and `low` are supposed to contain indexes, but when you update them after a failing guess, you set them to list elements rather than indexes. It should be:

```
   if guess==item:
        return mid
    elif guess>item:
        high=mid-1
    else: 
        low=mid+1
```

Comment: Yep, I c. I mix element and index together. I should have found it, it's a simple mistake. Thanks, Barmar.